# List of Layout folders required to define for Android App?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I am trying to define following layout folders

**layout/my_activity.xml**

**layout-large/my_activity.xml**

**layout-xlarge/my_activity.xml**

**layout-xlarge-land/my_activity.xml**

**layout-land/my_activity.xml**

**layout-sw600dp/my_activity.xml**

**layout-sw720dp/my_activity.xml**

Is this the complete list?Am i using all the possible layout folder combinations to **support all screen sizes**.

Sorry if it sounds silly but i am trying to confirm different layout folders i need to make for my App...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

With the new qualifiers you can define size qualifiers based on arbitrary dp so you can't list "all the possible combinations".

Comment: So you mean if i'm using **layout-sw600dp** then i don't need to use **layout-xlarge**..? My app will be supporting devices from Gingerbread till JB?Any suggestion which way i should define layout-folders??

Comment: They're not incompatible. From the docs: "xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp". sw600dp specifies that the screen should be in its smallest width at least 600dp. So they're different qualifiers.

Comment: Ok thanks..So am i going right by defining the layout folders the way i have defined them above in my question? Any suggestion would be helpful..

Comment: That depends on your app's specific needs. You don't *have* to define any of those qualifiers. You should use them whenever you need to. So for instance you might have a screen that does not need any specific layout for different screens, so you wouldn't need to use any of those folder qualifiers at all. I suggest you read the docs carefully, you might have a clearer vision thereafter.

Comment: Ok got it..Yeah i am too using these diff layout-folders only for certain activities..Will look into docs..Anyways thanks!!